# Is there a way to integrate CiviCRM with Ticketspice.com and other Event ticketing platforms like Eventbrite?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, payment-processor, developer

We're on Civi 4.6.17 and Drupal.

We're using ticketspice.com for an Event ticketing page, mostly because I have not figured out a way to create an Event registration page in Civi using the Discount codes extension. Our Ticketspice event registration page is [here](https://justiceworksny.ticketspice.com/justice-works-2016).

Has anyone created an integration between Ticketspice event pages and CiviCRM, or Eventbrite event pages? I have not had a chance to check out either the Ticketspice or Eventbrite APIs or webhooks.

UPDATE: We're using Authorize.net to process payments for tickets purchased on the Ticketspice event page, and it seems like there should be a way to pull in that data from Authorize to Civi. We also use the same Authorize account to process contributions, event fees/tickets made through Civi pages and price fields.

Answer (score 2):

Much easier to get Events working in CiviCRM and/or with CiviDiscount than to API integrate a third party ticketing system! You'd have to think about how to handle duplicate Contacts, get the monies right - where are any refunds being recorded etc.

Where are you stuck with Events in CiviCRM w/ CiviDiscount? What version of CiviCRM? Post a question on it - and we'll try help you out.

Comment: KarinG, thanks, will walk through my challenges with using CiviDiscount for Events. We're on Civi 4.6.17 and moving to 4.6.19 or 4.7.X soon.